Why is it MRT for budget lines and MRS for indifference curves when both are essentially the same thing?
Why is it marginal rate of TRANSFORMATION for budget lines, but marginal rate of SUBSTITUTION for indifference curves?
In both cases it is measuring the gradient, or in other words, the marginal rate of change for the curve. Hence, why do we say transformation for budget lines, but substitutition for indifference curves?
Why is it not just either MRS or MRT for both cases?
Thanks in advance. I never really understood this, maybe it's just one of those useless distinctions, so I thought I would ask this question.

MR-Transformation because it refers to the rate at which one good is transformed into another via some production process; while MR-Substitution because it measures the rate at which a good can be substituted by another in consumption without changing the level of utility.

The MRT need not be the slope of some budget line, it is more generally the slope of the feasible frontier. The MRT appears on the production side, while the MRS appears on the demand side. Apart from the different semantics of "substitution" and "transformation", using the same name for both would just lead to endless confusion, e.g. this chapter of a well known econ textbook would have to be renamed.

thanks for the response, that clears it up. my university uses that very same textbook haha
